# Hi am getting unexpected ')' error on line 65

Tags: laravel

Hi kindly help me check if there's any problem with my code. I am creating a command to generate a sitemap but am getting an error; 'unexpected ')' on line 65.

[here is the screenshot for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbU9c.png)

Comment: There is obviously a problem with your code. I'd go so far as to say it's on line 65.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask why you should not post screenshots of your code

Comment: Thanks so much @miken32 Solution by Jamer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is on the IF statement. Just remove the last OR operator from the condition. Like this:

```
 if (
        $url->segment(1) == $priority[0] ||
        $url->segment(1) == $priority[1] ||
        $url->segment(1) == $priority[2]
    ) {...}
```

If this is not the issue, maybe you can tell us what is the line 65.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the solution. Am so grateful

Comment: Questions that are the result of typographic errors or are otherwise unreproducible are not on-topic. Instead of answering them, leave a comment for the user if you have the reputation to do so, and flag the question for closure.